# Website search form transmits two questionmarks (??) instead of Umlauts ('ä', 'ö', 'ü') on certain machines

Tags: html, search, joomla, diacritics

Website and Database are set to UTF-8 and I added `accept-charset="utf-8"` to the form.

The things that seem strange to me are that it only happens on certain machines, but doesn't seem to be browser specific there. So far I could only reproduce it on Windows machines, but only on one out of five.
Another weird thing is that it's two Question-marks instead of a replacement character.

The search-logs on the server show the term with question-marks as well. The search performs correctly when you replace the question-marks with umlauts in the URL though.

The site runs on Joomla 2.5.4 if that's any help at all. I somehow suspect it to be a client-side settings problem though.

Anybody know what could be the cause of that?

Comment: If it is really a client side problem, we might be able to help by looking at the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if you can set the Content-Type to something like:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`

or `"utf-8"`